# combine multiple match() results in mongodb aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I got the following query:

```
db.getCollection('Messages').aggregate(
    { 
    $match : 
        { 
            "header.MessageType" : { $in: ["04"] },
        }

    },
    {
        $project:
          {
             _id: '$_id',
             header: '$header',
             content: '$content',
             q0: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$content.Changes", 0 ] },
             q1: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$content.Changes", 1 ] },
             q2: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$content.Changes", 2 ] },
             q3: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$content.Changes", 3 ] },
             q4: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$content.Changes", 4 ] },
             q5: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$content.Changes", 5 ] },
          }
    },
    {
        $match : 
        { 
            "q0":"1"
        }
    },
    { 
        $sort : { "sequenceID" : -1, } 
    },
    { 
        $limit : 1
    }
);
```

which gives me the following results:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57288ecb53f65928c4ba4995"),
    "header" : {
        "MessageType" : "04",
        ...
    },
    "content" : {
        ...
    },
    "q0" : "1",
    "q1" : "0",
    "q2" : "1",
    "q3" : "0",
    "q4" : "0",
    "q5" : "0"
```

the query gives me the most recent document (according to sequenceID) which its 'q0' is definitely  equals to 1 (other qx fields might be 0 or 1). 
I want to do the same for q1,q2,...,q5. In other words, I want a result containing 6 records each of which representing the most recent document that its 'qn' (n=0..5) record is definitely '0'.

is it possible to repeat the following part 6 times (for different qx values in $match section) and then combine them?

```
{
    $match : 
    { 
        "q0":"1"
    }
},
{ 
    $sort : { "sequenceID" : -1, } 
},
{ 
    $limit : 1
}
```

Or is there any better solution for this?

--- EDIT (some sample [and simplified] data added):

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57288fa553f65928c4bf4b2b"),
    "header" : {
        "MessageType" : "04"
    },
    "content" : {
        "Changes" : [ 
            "0", 
            "1", 
            "1", 
            "1", 
            "1", 
            "0"
        ]
    },
    "sequenceID" : NumberLong(369851),
    "messageDate" : 13950214
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57288fa453f65928c4bf4863"),
    "header" : {
        "MessageType" : "04"
    },
    "content" : {
        "Changes" : [ 
            "0", 
            "0", 
            "1", 
            "0", 
            "0", 
            "0"
        ]
    },
    "sequenceID" : NumberLong(369139),
    "messageDate" : 13950214
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57288fa353f65928c4bf43c2"),
    "header" : {
        "MessageType" : "04"
    },
    "content" : {
        "Changes" : [ 
            "0", 
            "1", 
            "0", 
            "0", 
            "0", 
            "0"
        ]
    },
    "sequenceID" : NumberLong(367953),
    "messageDate" : 13950214
}
```

Each document indicates one or more (up to 6) modifications. The modifications are seen in the q0..q5 fields. What I need as the output is the most recent changes for each qx field. the order of documents can be determined by the "sequenceID" field. In other words if I (logically do an) OR the q0..q5 of all documents in the result, it should be ["1","1","1","1","1","1"].

Comment: you want multiple match statements? if it is then it's possible.

Comment: it hard to guess as there is no input document example - which could drive other solution that proposed in my answer

Comment: @rummykhan what I need is multiple match statements operating on the same stage of the pipeline concurrently. Is that possible?

Comment: @profesor79 I added some sample data, meanwhile I'm checking your answer.

Comment: @rummykhan Then could you please explain your solution as an answer?

Comment: Yes sure wait a while

Comment: @rummykhan btw, I need multiple match, sort and limit statements to be executed concurrently, not only the match part.

Comment: can you tell what is your desired output.. because i'm unable to understand

Comment: @rummykhan please read the last part that I added to the question. hope it clears the problem for you.

Answer (score 7):

Actually `aggregate` function is known as a pipeline just because it pipes the data from one aggregate operator to other and it is upto you that how much pipes you need to get the final result.

```
e.g.
$match -> $project -> $group -> $sort -> $match -> $sort -> $limit -> $project
```

You can use any operator multiple times.

```
db.getCollection('Messages').aggregate(
 [
  { $match : { "header.MessageType" : { $in: ["04"] }}},
  {
        $project:
          {
             _id: '$_id',
             "MessageType": '$header.MessageType',
             q0: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$content.Changes", 0 ] },
             q1: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$content.Changes", 1 ] },
             q2: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$content.Changes", 2 ] },
             q3: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$content.Changes", 3 ] },
             q4: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$content.Changes", 4 ] },
             q5: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$content.Changes", 5 ] },
          }
  },
  {$match : { "q0" : "0" } },
  {$sort : { "q1" : -1}},
  {$match : {"q3" : "1"}}
 ]
)
```

Now last thing to add is adding as you're saying 6 match clauses even if you're using an index will slow down your query and in case your collection is huge it will take some time to pipe all the data from aggregate pipeline. So use this pipeline wisely.

Comment: well the first match pipes out the other documents which I need be considered in the other match statements. that's the issue.

Comment: i got your point let me see what i can do and update my question

Answer (score 2):

after $match executed - documents which aren't selected are removed from process pipe.

what I could propose is replace

```
{
    $match : 
    { 
        "q0":"1"
    }
},
```

with

```
{
    $group:{
        _id:{include fields here},
        q0:{$push:"$q0"},
        ...............,
        q5:{$push:"$q5"}
 },

}
```

after that we can operate on array having full result set.

so we can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)

```
{ $filter: { input: "q0", as: q0Filtered, cond: {$eq:1} } }
```

Will that work for you?

Any comments welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use more than one match in a query and if it does get executed all statement other than first match will be ignored.

Comment: Is that true? Seems like this answer is conflicting other answers up there.